# Python check through two lists

Tags: python

I am relatively new to python and I came across a problem given below:

Given two lists a and b and an integer n, Check if
a) All elements of a is a factor of n
b) n is a factor of all elements of b

My code doesn't seem to be correct. Can someone please point out the mistake here.

```
return n if n%x==0 for x in a and y%n==0 for y in b
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you expecting this function to return a `bool` value stating whether or not both conditions are met?

Comment: For loop doesn't work like that. Post the full code please.

Comment: `return all(n % x == 0 for n in a) and all(y % n == 0 for y in b)`

Comment: @JPI93 yeah returning true or false should be enough...in this case, I tried to return the integer itself if it satisfies both the conditions

Comment: @Chris_Rands Thanks...I think i got confused in using for loop syntax instead of all() :)

Comment: @Dev5 The above comment from @Chris_Rands is spot on if you just want a `bool` returned. You could use his solution in an `if`/`else` tree if you wanted to do something like "Return `False`/`None` if doesn't pass, Return `int` if it does`.

Comment: You don't have to do it all on one line, if you're getting confused. The real trick here is the builtin function "all".

Comment: @JPI93 okay yeah sorry my question wasn't fully accurate. Thanks for the additional information :)

Comment: @KennyOstrom Yeah well actually I specifically wanted a one-liner...and the one I wrote was incorrect so I wanted to know my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obvious one (you were missing `all(...)`):

```
all(n % x == 0 for x in a) and all(y % n == 0 for y in b)
```

Fun one:

```
0 == n % reduce(lcm, a) == reduce(gcd, b) % n
```

Requires Python 3.9, though.

Test code:

```
from itertools import product
from math import gcd, lcm
from functools import reduce

R = range(1, 11)
true = false = 0
for n in R:
    for a in product(R, repeat=3):
        for b in product(R, repeat=3):
            expect = all(n % x == 0 for x in a) and all(y % n == 0 for y in b)
            result = 0 == n % reduce(lcm, a) == reduce(gcd, b) % n
            assert result == expect
            true += expect
            false += not expect
print(true, false)
```

=> No failures, same 2,723 true results and 9,997,277 false results.